# Why is it different putting the width style in the first <td>s or the second in an html table / Why are these tables rendered differently?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can you explain why these two HTML codes result in different look when rendered? [**fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/6p9K3/626/) and [**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6p9K3/627/)

The only difference in the code is that in **fiddle1** `style="width: 50px;"` is in the first row of the table, while in **fiddle2** it is in the second row. But this results in different widths for each one.

According to Chrome Dev Tools **fiddle1** both cells/columns have 51px width (should be `50px` anyways), and in **fiddle2** the first cells/columns have `49px` width and the second `50px` width.

Markup in Fiddle 1

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;">Test</td>
      <td style="width: 50px;">Testing 1123455</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td>B</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Markup in Fiddle 2

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Testing 1123455</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td style="width: 50px;">B</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS for both fiddles

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the magic of 'table-layout: fixed'.
As specified in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values_2)

The table-layout CSS property specifies the algorithm used to lay out  cells, rows, and columns.

When the value is 'fixed': Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

**In your first case**: As you specified the width for columns of first row. Rendering algorithm takes the width and renders it with that width. The extra 1px you see, is just the border width.

**In Second Case**: As there is no width for first row specified. It takes the table width and try to adjust the row columns in it. As for two columns there will be three borders, we left with the 97px to be divided among the two columns. As pixel cannot be divided into decimals, you get 48px and 49px width of columns. extra 1px is for the border width